# Perguntas a respeito de preferências de programação são permitidas?

Tags: debate

Fiz uma pergunta a respeito do uso de ' ou " em strings literais em JavaScript que gerou uma discussão interessante a respeito de preferências entre uma opção e outra.

Pessoalmente acho interessante saber das preferências de colegas de profissão e as suas justificativas, para rever as minhas próprias preferências e aprender coisas novas.

Portanto, deixo o questionamento: perguntas a respeito de preferências são permitidas? Se sim, como fazê-las de maneira correta?

Comment: Nós estamos neste exato momento criando uma opção fora do site (iniciativa de alguns usuários, nada relacionado com a dona deste site) para ter essas discussões, aqui no site só trabalhamos com respostas objetivas. Cada tipo de formato deve estar no seu devido lugar.

Comment: Tenho muito interesse nessa iniciativa, @bigown. Caso não seja confidencial, gostaria de acompanhar de alguma forma.

Comment: Vamos iniciar as discussões hoje, se tiver aderência da comunidade: https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/